# Binding not working when I use Angular-trix in a modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular-trix.
I launch a modal (bootstrap) but the binding does not work.

If I put the binding in a div, I can see it is passed into modal however for the angular-trix component it does not appear.

My code is:

```
         $scope.editCommentDialog = function (comment) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'editCommentDialog.html',
                windowClass : 'edit-comment-modal-dialog',
                controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, editedComment) {
                    $scope.editedComment = editedComment;

                    $scope.ok = function () {
                        $modalInstance.close(editedComment);
                    };

                    $scope.cancel = function () {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                },
                resolve: {
                    editedComment: function () {
                       return { id : comment.id,  text : comment.text};
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (editedComment) {
                $scope.editedComment = editedComment;
                $scope.updateComment();
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
```

and

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="editCommentDialog.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Edit</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="editedComment.text" class="trix-content editable-trix-editor"></trix-editor>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `$scope.editedComment = editedComment;` form your `.then` callback?

Comment: I removed it and still there is no binding.

Comment: anyone have any luck on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="editedComment.text" class="trix-content editable-trix-editor"></trix-editor>
```

To your code add ng-if="true" so it will look now :

```
<trix-editor ng-if="true" angular-trix ng-model="editedComment.text" class="trix-content editable-trix-editor"></trix-editor>
```

and it solves the problem